# NGINX configuartion to proxy SSL requests to a Sinatra server

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, nginx, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy

I have a key, certificate and a chain certificate. 
The domain looks like automation.mydomain.com

I have a Sinatra server running on `localhost:3000`, confirmed via `curl localhost:3000/test`.

I'd like to redirect port 80 and port 443 traffic to 3000. Here's my `/etc/sites-enabled/sinatra` config:

```
upstream app_aggregator {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 8;
}

# the nginx server instance
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name automation.mydomain.com my_site;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/aggregator.log;

    # pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers
    # and much more can be added, see nginx config options
    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://app_aggregator/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
 }
```

Note the above does not work (http://automation.mydomain.com/ results in `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`). I'm not sure how to add the key, normal certificate and the chain certificate into this mix.

I've solved this problem in the past with a node.js config which happily consumed the keys and the SSL worked just fine, but I've never used nginx.

It's worth noting I'm using Amazon AWS and only have 80 and 443 open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's something wrong with the DNS configuration for your domain, hard to tell you what's wrong without knowing more about your setup, but at least make sure that you have the name servers for your domain properly set up and an A-record pointing to your AWS-instance.

An important thing to note when configuring HTTPS with Nginx is that your certificate file should include any intermediate certificates that you might have. See the link to the Nginx documentation below for more information.

Setting up SSL with Nginx can be as simple as adding these 3 lines to your configuration:

```
listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /path/to/your/certificate
ssl_certificate /path/to/your/certificate_key
```

If you want to enforce HTTPS you can disable HTTP (port 80) on your existing server block and create an additional one like this:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name automation.mydomain.com my_site;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

This will redirect any HTTP-request to your HTTPS-enabled server. Note that I would advice changing 301 to 302 while testing so that your browser doesn't cache the response.

See these resources for more information

- [nginx ssl module documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html)
- [Strong SSL Security on nginx by Raymii](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html)